# TouchImageView & Volley NetworkImageView working together

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview, touchimageview

I'm Using a ViewPager in my project and so far i found Volley to be very good at loading in the images for the individual pages.

Volley needs `com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView` and TouchImageView needs `com.android.touch.TouchImageView` for ImageView in the xml

My question is how i do combine both of these

I cant get the zoom to work when using Volley

Or i can get the zoom to work by loading in standard bitmaps but swapping pages is slow with that and i'm not that experienced with Bitmaps cashing etc hence why i need volley for the easy of use.

Is there a way to get both of these to work together.

My Pager code

[image]

Thanks

**UPD**

I noticed in touch view class `public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {`

I wonder if changing to `public class TouchImageView extends NetworkImageView {` would make it work.

but i moved on since i asked the Q and now use uni image loaded instead. Just out of interest Ill give this a go at some stage and report back. It may be that simple

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are sure the issue is with this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(entry.data, 0, entry.data.length);
```

then you can run this in an `AsyncTask` and that'll be better I think.

But I suggest you using `Picasso` library for image loading, because there are many articles out there that say `Picasso` is faster in image loading and handles all the hard work itself (caching and...).

Then you can use `TouchImageView` with `Picasso.load(urlString).into(touchImageView);`

Comment: I tried Picasso and universal image loader and it was the same. I would have thought it will be faster loading in the images being in cache but there was a pause of a few seconds. It comes down to how large is the image is so small ones would be ok but full hd or 4k is a problem. with volleys NetworkImaveView no problem so i would like to be able zoom too

Comment: So you're telling that in your case `Picasso` has problem loading high-resolution (4K for example) images? That's not right at least for me! I think the problem is with `TouchImageView` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/issues/71) .`TouchImageView` doesn't handle large images well! So I suggest you using Chris Bane's [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) with almost the same features as `TouchImageView` which I have used and can confirm has no problem with large images.

Comment: I just tried Photoview and it looks fast. I also downloaded the universal image loader full demo from github and the viewpager demo looks promising. i try and combine the zoom and get back to you. thanks

Comment: Ok i just tested with uni img loaded and touchview with 4k images. Looks good and fast so i will use that. Thanks for your help